# Using javascript, how do I permanently delete a storage sync record stored in a firefox profile

Tags: firefox-addon, storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

I created a firefox web extension that stores data describing search engines in storage sync. The data actually gets stored in a file named storage-sync.sqlite. I've noticed that [browser.storage.sync.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/remove) actually changes the hidden property "_status" from "created" to "deleted", but it doesn't actually delete a record.

Is it possible to permanently delete the entire record from js script in my web extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: no, the status is used for synchronisation purposes.

[Kinto](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Kinto) (the storage backend used by sync) sets the _status field so other browsers that sync to the current browser know "hey, I should remove this". I have no idea when it's actually removed, but I don't think it stays around forever.

A note on passwords from Kinto, which seems to confirm the function of _status for storage-sync.sqlite:

> We detect kB changing by storing the current kB (as a hash) in the
>   keyring record itself. We "update" this keyring record with the
>   current kB hash on every call to sync(). kinto.js tries to track the
>   status of the keyring in a field called _status -- it should be
>   "synced" when it is the same as the version that we expect on the
>   server, and it should be "updated" if we've changed it and haven't
>   pushed it to the server. So after possibly updating the kB hash (or
>   just replacing it with what it already is), we check if the keyring is
>   "updated" and if so, try to upload it to the server. Because
>   encryption happens "just-in-time", this causes the keyring to be
>   reuploaded but encrypted by the new kB.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/CloudServices/Sync/ExtensionStorage_Design_Doc#Password_changes